# Deploy python venv as snap

Tags: python, snapcraft

We have a python(3) venv rest api. In the same venv we have also installed and configured the application server `uwsgi` the api is running on. And we are looking for a clean way to deploy it.

Until now we are deploying with is a simple script that creates the venv install the dependencies from pip and then runs the app.

I am wondering if using snap would be possible to package everything nicely and simply install them on a server.

Is that possible or a good practice to deploy a web api this way?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with snaps. You can use the python plugin module with snapcraft which extends your python path with a virtualenv.

Also, Its pretty easy to do this with a deb.

dh-virtualenv lets you use standard debian packaging tools.  https://labs.spotify.com/2013/10/10/packaging-in-your-packaging-dh-virtualenv/

It is your choice.